# Put SwiftUI Menu in NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swiftui, contextmenu, swiftui-navigationlink

Is there a way to have a `Menu` inside of a `NavigationLink`? Where tapping on the `NavigationLink` would navigate to a separate view, and tapping on the Menu button would open a context menu.

In the screenshot below, I would like to be able to tap on the row to navigate to a new view and tap on the 3-dot button to open a context menu. Currently, tapping on the button and row navigates to the separate view. I have to long press on the 3-dot button for the context menu to open.

Here is the code for the `NavigationLink` I have now:

```
NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
            HStack {
                Text("Hello, World!").foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
                Spacer()
                Menu {
                    Button("Action 1", action: {})

                    Button("Action 2", action: {})
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName:"ellipsis")
                        .frame(width: 24.0, height: 24.0)
                        .background(Color(UIColor.tertiarySystemFill))
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(4.0)
                }
            }
            .padding(16)
            .background(Color.init(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground))
        }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How about putting the `Menu` outside of `NavigationLink` instead, something like `HStack{ NavigationLink{}; Menu{} }`?

Comment: A `NavigationLink` is for all intents and purposes a button that pushes a view, you cant but a `Menu`/`contextMenu` on the link but you can put it next to it.